# how to write column name with space in pdo prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i did not make these column name as they are created by uploading CSV file
as 'COL 1' 'COL 2'

```
   connect();
   global $db;
   $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET 'COL 1'=:c1 where table1_id=:id");
    $sql->bindParam(':id',$arry['id'],PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);

    $sql->bindParam(':c1',$arry['t1'],PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    try
    {
    $sql->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo($e);
    }
```

the error showing is

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1='DDEE' where table1_id='5'' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\excelsheets\functions.php:109 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\excelsheets\functions.php(109): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\wamp\www\excelsheets\save4.php(4): save4_update(Array) #2 {main}

I know we can't use '' single quotes in prepared statement
then how can i represent a column with space in between?

Comment: backtics (below the tilde) around your column names should do it.

Comment: you mean 'COL 1' this is not allowed

Comment: No, `COL 1`.  the backtick is also a markup character at SO.  Its just below the escape key and to the left of the `1` key.

Comment: @Mike i did not make these column name as they are created by uploading CSV file as 'COL 1' 'COL 2'

Comment: What about `str_replace(' ', '_', $column_name)` before doing the insert into the DB?

Comment: main emphasis on handling space!!

Comment: You're going to be typing a lot of backticks with those very descriptive column names.

Comment: Ya, @Mike.  I think we agree, spaces are bad.  But you are oversimplifying the solution to that problem.  What if he's getting this csv from a client, then it gets imported with some other app?   OP's question is clearly different

Comment: @paqogomez I agree it's different and doesn't answer the specific problem. However you *did* answer it in your first comment. No sense in re-stating it again when you're already right.

Comment: Thanks a alot `` worked in pdo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character in MySQL is the back quote (or back tick).  Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET `COL 1` = :c1
     where table1_id = :id
```